# Selecting the service account on GCP Console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, terraform-provider-gcp

I have a cloud environment where I can't use the default service account because of security rules and I can also not add any credentials.json for authentication.

I am trying to deploy a terraform file using the gcloud console and when I try to deploy, it uses the default service account and it is disabled.

Even trying the command to setup the service account

```
gcloud config set account SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL
```

I still getting the error that it tries to deploy with the default service account.

How can I bypass it, how can I authenticate to the new service account with less privilage or at least deploy with my user account, hence I am already authenticated, because I use the console directly on the cloud?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Terraform to use other service account either setting the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to point to the service account JSON file or by specifying google provider `credentials` in your *.tf file.

You can also check this [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/getting_started#configuring-the-provider) for reference